# State whether the following series converges or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

So for finding if the sequences converges or diverges I was going to use the limit comparison test. I was thinking with K/ (K$^2$)$^1/2$ but wouldn't that just be 1? Help please!

Comment: The terms of the sequence don't approach $0$.  What can one conclude?

Comment: It automatically diverges right. How do you know the terms don't approach 0 though? Can you factor the radical to those terms?

Comment: Take the limit as $k\to \infty$.  The limit is $1$.  You can divide the numerator and denominator by $k$ to obtain $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+1/k^2}}$

Comment: can you show me step by step how to take that limit? I am a little confused with the radical? I mean its in indeterminate form right?

Comment: I would use L'Hopitals rule and take the derivative of the numerator and denominator, correct?

Comment: You could use LHR if you like, but need not do so if you read my previous comment.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure